# sum of bessel functions times exponentials

Tags: special-functions, bessel-functions

I stepped upon the following sum as part of my research, I haven't been able to solve.

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{e^{i\cdot n\cdot a}}\cdot J_n(z)$

where $a$ and $z$ are both complex numbers, and $J_n$ is the n-th Bessel function.

I tried expanding the Bessel function into a series, this yields the following result

$e^{i\cdot z\cdot \sin(a)}- \sum_{m=0}^{\infty}{{(-z/2\cdot e^{-i\cdot a})^m}/({m!})} \sum_{s=0}^{m}{{(z/2\cdot e^{i\cdot a})^s}/{(s!)}}$

I can also change the summation order, but this gets me nowhere.

it would be great to know if there exists a closed form to this sum.

Comment: This is in the vicinity of the [Jacobi-Anger expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi%E2%80%93Anger_expansion). However, that involves a sum over all integer $n$ rather than only positive $n$.

Comment: True, but because of the missing $i^n$ it does not work. I tried looking up in the integral table, and I haven't seen anything which get me closer to solving this type of sum.

Comment: As another indication of this being a non-standard sum: Mathematica knows that $$\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty w^n J_n(z)=e^{\frac{z}{2}(w-1/w)},$$ but it doesn't yield a closed form if we restrict to $n\geq 1$.

Comment: I used it to simplify another part of the problem, but it does help this sum. I tried using even odd identities of Bessel functions and got an identity but it does not seem to help